# Why would my resultset be coming up as false?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm working on a project for my programming class and the teacher encourages to use stackoverflow for assistance. My problem is as follows: in my if with `sResult.next()` is coming back false. I'm trying to obtain one row from my derby database.

I have verified my productUuid is obtaining a UUID, preparedstatement is active. I have checked that my findAll for the query is working and it is.

The interceptor is supposed to return the class name that is being used.

My query:

```
private static final String QUERY_02 =
            "SELECT oid, product_name, product_desc, product_price, product_sku, product_inv FROM PRODUCT WHERE oid=?";
```

My UUIDUtils:

```
public class UUIDUtils {

    public static UUID asUuid(byte[] bytes) {
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        final long firstLong = bb.getLong();
        final long secondLong = bb.getLong();

        return new UUID(firstLong, secondLong);
    }

    public static byte[] asBytes(UUID uuid) {
        final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
        bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
        bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());

        return bb.array();
    }
```

My singleProduct:

```
public ProductDTO singleProduct(UUID productUuid) throws MyStoreException {
        log().trace("Entered singleProduct()");
         ProductDTO sProduct = null;


          try (final Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
                     final PreparedStatement sPre = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY_02);) {  


              sPre.setBytes(1, UUIDUtils.asBytes(productUuid));
                  log().trace("PreparedStatment connection is active: {}", !sPre.isClosed());
              log().trace("productUuid passed through ProductQueryImpl: {}" , productUuid);
              ResultSet sResult = sPre.executeQuery();

              if(sResult.next()) { 

             sProduct = new ProductDTO(productUuid,
                        sResult.getString("product_name"),
                        sResult.getString("product_desc"),
                        sResult.getDouble("product_price"),
                        sResult.getString("product_sku"),
                        sResult.getInt("product_inv"));


                }else {
                    log().error("Product not found");
                }
                return sProduct;


            }catch(final SQLException ex2) {
            log().error(ex2.getMessage(), ex2);
            throw new MyStoreException(ex2.getMessage());
            }




          }
```

My Console:

```
00:05:04,092 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.mvc.model.ProductModel] (default task-1) Entered postConstruct()
00:05:04,094 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.interceptors.LogInterceptors] (default task-1) Entered logInterceptor(context)
00:05:04,094 DEBUG [ca.sait.mystore.interceptors.LogInterceptors] (default task-1) Method Name: singleProduct
00:05:04,094 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.dao.ProductQueryImpl] (default task-1) Entered singleProduct()
00:05:04,096 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.dao.ProductQueryImpl] (default task-1) PreparedStatment connection is active: true
00:05:04,096 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.dao.ProductQueryImpl] (default task-1) productUuid passed through ProductQueryImpl: 00b6d373-af18-54ed-f8c9-7f9d986a834a
00:05:04,097 ERROR [ca.sait.mystore.dao.ProductQueryImpl] (default task-1) Product not found
00:05:04,098 DEBUG [ca.sait.mystore.interceptors.LogInterceptors] (default task-1) Returning Null
00:05:04,098 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.interceptors.LogInterceptors] (default task-1) Exited logInterceptor(context)
00:05:04,099 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.mvc.model.ProductModel] (default task-1) Following UUID passed through Model:  00b6d373-af18-54ed-f8c9-7f9d986a834a
00:05:04,099 TRACE [ca.sait.mystore.mvc.model.ProductModel] (default task-1) Exited postConstruct()
```

Comment: what do you mean "false" ?

Comment: Do you mean `sResult.next()` returns false? If that's the case, then the SQL didn't find a matching row. Have you tried changing `sPre.setBytes(...)` to `sPre.setString(...)` and passing the UUID as a string?

Comment: What is the data type of column OID in [derby] database table PRODUCT? Are you sure you are providing the correct value for `productUuid`?

Comment: `sResult.next()` is coming up as false, sorry didn't clarify properly. the datatype of OID in derby is char 16 bit data. I'm using a btyeBuffer to wrap the uuid.

Comment: It looks to me that in this line of the code you posted - `sPre.setBytes(1, UUIDUtils.asBytes(productUuid));` - the generated value does not exist in your database. Is there some way you can verify this?